# Bluetooth stopped working after Windows Update with dualboot

Tags: drivers, bluetooth

I have a dual-boot on an HP ENVY x360 Convertible laptop consisting of Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04. When I first installed Ubuntu, everything worked as expected, however, when Windows automatically updated it somehow broke bluetooth on Ubuntu.

Bluetooth isn't hard or soft blocked. When I try to run `bluetoothctl power on` it just returns saying that there is no bluetooth controller detected. Lastly, the mac address for my bluetooth controller just returns 0s.

My bluetooth/wifi card is: Intel Wireless-AC 9560 160MHz

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Same problem on my desktop PC with an Asus B450-I, except `bluetoothctl power on` just hangs forever (`bluetoothctl` gets stuck on `Waiting to connect to bluetoothd...`) and also all my audio input and output devices are gone. Tried disabling and re-enabling Bluetooth in BIOS without luck.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on my desktop PC with an Asus B450-I, except `bluetoothctl power on` would just hang forever (`bluetoothctl` would get stuck on `Waiting to connect to bluetoothd...`). Also, all my audio input and output devices were gone, except for a "Dummy output". Tried disabling and re-enabling Bluetooth in BIOS, rebooting, turning of Fast Boot etc without luck.

Although I don't understand how I ended up here in the first place, turns out the problem was that my kernel had been upgraded to 5.8. Reverting to 5.4 brought back Bluetooth and audio. I accomplished this by booting into 5.4 (so I wouldn't delete a running kernel) using the **Advanced options for Ubuntu** option in GRUB and doing `sudo apt purge linux-image-5.8.0-36-generic linux-modules-5.8.0-36-generic`. (You should probably do something like `sudo apt list --installed "*linux-image*"` to check what version(s) you have installed.)